# How to find items in multiple strings that match with items from a list

Tags: python, feedparser

Hi I am trying to make a filter for a piratebay movie rss feed, which filters out the movies I already acquired and keeps the ones I do not currently have. It will then later on download the torrent from the magnet link provided. The problem is I can't figure out how to filter out the movies I have from the ones I don't, as I am trying to filter a list from a string and do not know a way around it. Here is a run-able example, with the code I want to add in notes:

```
import feedparser
import ssl

if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
feed = feedparser.parse('https://thepiratebay.org/rss/top100/207')
feed_title = feed['feed']['title']
feed_entries = feed.entries
f = open("movies.txt", "r+")
fr = f.readlines()
print(fr)
for entry in feed.entries[:25]:
    el = entry.title.lower()
    # if fr in el:
        # remove_from_titles()
    # else:
    article_title = el
    article_link = entry.link
    print(article_title)
    print(article_link)
```

movies.txt file:

```
aquaman
spiderman
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
with open("movies.txt", "r+") as f:
    fr = f.readlines()
if article_title.lower() not in movies_list:
    print(article_title)
    # do your downloading stuff here

    # update your movies.txt file
    with open("movies.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write('\n' + 'article_title')
```

Comment: The problem with doing it that way is that I am not able to append to the list and add the movies I download using the script, as I want it to be fully automated.

Comment: still getting the same output as before

Comment: what is the `output` that you are getting

Comment: aquaman.2018.1080p.webrip.x264-mp4
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:B6E82665EF588BB6574DB1F9780A0279274F407D&dn=Aquaman.2018.1080p.WEBRip.x264-MP4
fantastic.beasts.the.crimes.of.grindelwald.2018.1080p.webrip.x26
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:426EC6D01964BAC82C0DA451B8E67842608FCC61&dn=Fantastic.Beasts.The.Crimes.Of.Grindelwald.2018.1080p.WEBRip.x26
a.star.is.born.2018.1080p.webrip.x264-mp4
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:FC0CCE628DBE7EEA0CF655A6A13336791021F25F&dn=A.Star.is.Born.2018.1080p.WEBRip.x264-MP4

Answer (score 0):

Try to use set instead of list. If feed set is **A** and file titles **B** then the tittles in A that are not in B is `A.difference(B)`